Deneb click on axis label to cross filter
With a stacked bar chart made with Deneb, if I click on a bar segment it cross filters on that segment.  Is it possible to click on the label for the bar to filter on the entire bar?
In this example, clicking on the category (bar segment) works, however I want to click on the axis labels ('top', 'bottom') and have the entire bar filtered, similar to what happens in a stacked bar in the built in power bi stacked bar visual.

{
"data": {
    "values": [
      {"category": "a", "xval": 1, "yval": "top"},
      {"category": "b", "xval": 5, "yval": "top"},
      {"category": "c", "xval": 8, "yval": "top"},
      {"category": "a", "xval": 3, "yval": "bottom"},
      {"category": "b", "xval": 1, "yval": "bottom"},
      {"category": "c", "xval": 9, "yval": "bottom"}
    ]
  },
  "encoding": {
    "y": {
      "title": null,
      "field": "yval",
      "sort": "descending"
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "bar",
        "tooltip": true
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "title": null,
          "field": "xval",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "aggregate": "sum"
        },
        "color": {"field": "category"},
        "order": {"field": "category"}
      }
    }
  ]
}


Does this have to be Vega-Lite or can it be Vega?

It can be Vega too

Here you go.
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "background": "white",
  "padding": 5,
  "width": 200,
  "style": "cell",
  "data": [
    {"name": "dataset"},
    {
      "name": "data_0",
      "source": "dataset",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "aggregate",
          "groupby": [
            "yval",
            "category"
          ],
          "ops": ["sum"],
          "fields": ["xval"],
          "as": ["sum_xval"]
        },
        {
          "type": "stack",
          "groupby": ["yval"],
          "field": "sum_xval",
          "sort": {
            "field": ["category"],
            "order": ["ascending"]
          },
          "as": [
            "sum_xval_start",
            "sum_xval_end"
          ],
          "offset": "zero"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "data_1",
      "source": "dataset",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "aggregate",
          "groupby": ["yval"],
          "ops": ["sum"],
          "fields": ["xval"],
          "as": ["sum_xval"]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "signals": [
    {"name": "y_step", "value": 20},
    {
      "name": "height",
      "update": "bandspace(domain('y').length, 0.1, 0.05) * y_step"
    }
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "name": "layer_0_marks",
      "type": "rect",
      "style": ["bar"],
      "from": {"data": "data_0"},
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "tooltip": {
            "signal": "{\"Sum of xval\": format(datum[\"sum_xval\"], \"\"), \"yval\": isValid(datum[\"yval\"]) ? datum[\"yval\"] : \"\"+datum[\"yval\"], \"category\": isValid(datum[\"category\"]) ? datum[\"category\"] : \"\"+datum[\"category\"]}"
          },
          "fill": {
            "scale": "color",
            "field": "category"
          },
          "ariaRoleDescription": {
            "value": "bar"
          },
          "description": {
            "signal": "\"Sum of xval: \" + (format(datum[\"sum_xval\"], \"\")) + \"; yval: \" + (isValid(datum[\"yval\"]) ? datum[\"yval\"] : \"\"+datum[\"yval\"]) + \"; category: \" + (isValid(datum[\"category\"]) ? datum[\"category\"] : \"\"+datum[\"category\"])"
          },
          "x": {
            "scale": "x",
            "field": "sum_xval_end"
          },
          "x2": {
            "scale": "x",
            "field": "sum_xval_start"
          },
          "y": {
            "scale": "y",
            "field": "yval"
          },
          "height": {
            "signal": "max(0.25, bandwidth('y'))"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "axisClick",
      "type": "rect",
      "from": {"data": "data_1"},
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "fill": {"value": "transparent"},
          "x": {"value": -40},
          "x2": {"value": 0},
          "y": {
            "scale": "y",
            "field": "yval"
          },
          "height": {
            "signal": "max(0.25, bandwidth('y'))"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "x",
      "type": "linear",
      "domain": {
        "data": "data_0",
        "fields": [
          "sum_xval_start",
          "sum_xval_end"
        ]
      },
      "range": [0, {"signal": "width"}],
      "nice": true,
      "zero": true
    },
    {
      "name": "y",
      "type": "band",
      "domain": {
        "data": "dataset",
        "field": "yval",
        "sort": {
          "order": "descending",
          "field": "key"
        }
      },
      "range": {
        "step": {"signal": "y_step"}
      },
      "paddingInner": 0.1,
      "paddingOuter": 0.05
    },
    {
      "name": "color",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "domain": {
        "data": "data_0",
        "field": "category",
        "sort": true
      },
      "range": "category"
    }
  ],
  "axes": [
    {
      "scale": "x",
      "orient": "bottom",
      "grid": false,
      "labelFlush": true,
      "labelOverlap": true,
      "tickCount": {
        "signal": "ceil(width/40)"
      },
      "zindex": 0
    },
    {
      "scale": "y",
      "orient": "left",
      "grid": false,
      "zindex": 0
    }
  ],
  "legends": [
    {
      "fill": "color",
      "symbolType": "square",
      "title": "category"
    }
  ]
}

